# Makefile issues: g++: fatal error: no input files

Tags: c++, makefile, file-not-found

**What I've already done:**

I've looked through other StackOverflow threads with similar issues, but none of them seem to apply to my specific case. I've also double checked to makes sure that the correct files are in the correct locations (folders) and that everything is named properly as well.

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
[employee_xyz@petco.com]$ make
g++ -Wall -O2 -ansi -pedantic -o dog.cpp
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mscp.o] Error 4
```

Here's the makefile in question:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -ansi -pedantic -Werror

TARGETS = dog dog.o collar.o

dog: dog.o collar.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o dog collar.o dog.o

dog.o: dog.cpp collar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o dog.cpp

collar.o: collar.cpp collar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o collar.cpp

clean:
    -rm -f ${TARGETS}
```

Here are the files (they're all in the same directory) that are being referenced by the makefile:

```
-collar.cpp
-collar.h
-makefile
-dog.cpp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-o.htm

Comment: Sorry, I meant dog.cpp. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
dog.o: dog.cpp collar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o dog.cpp

collar.o: collar.cpp collar.h
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o collar.cpp
```

should read

```
dog.o: dog.cpp collar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c dog.cpp

collar.o: collar.cpp collar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c collar.cpp
```

Comment: Ah, shoot that's what I was missing. I forgot to include the name of the executable after "-o". I experimented with replacing "-o" with "-c" and that worked too. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Note that when using `-c` with `file.cpp`, the name of the output file is by default `file.o`, so you can omit `-o file.o` unless you don't want the default filename for the object file.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing

```
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) - c collar.cpp -o compiledfilename
```

Compiledfilename is the name of the binary file.

Comment: Use $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c collar.cpp - o binaryfilename

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late to answer. But this might help some else. I had the same issue. And I fixed it by replacing **.h** file with **.hpp** file. It worked :)