# gcc: fatal error: no input files

Tags: gcc, makefile, mpi

I am trying to compile some source code but I presented with the following error output after entering "make":

```
mpicc -c -O3 -I        func_pointer.c
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [func_pointer.o] Error 4
```

I have seen other threads on this website relating to this error output ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591240/error-1-no-input-files-when-making-a-c-file), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140800/makefile-error-no-such-file-or-directory-no-input-files), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653680/makefile-issues-g-fatal-error-no-input-files)). I was in fact experiencing a similar problem previously, which I think I may have solved, where the "make" command was producing:

```
make: Circular mod_prec.o <- mod_prec.o dependency dropped.
make: Circular mod_prec.o <- mod_prec.o dependency dropped.
make: Circular mod_prec.o <- mod_prec.o dependency dropped.
/usr/bin/cpp -P -C -traditional  -DIFORT -P -C -traditional    -DWET_DRY -DMULTIPROCESSOR    -DLIMITED_NO  -DGCN                                        mod_prec.F > mod_prec.f90
mpif90  -c  -O3 -I        mod_prec.f90
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mod_prec.o] Error 4
```

I followed the steps suggested on this [website](http://forum.abinit.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1686), which I think may have addressed that issue (I believe I am progressing further through the makefile). Those steps are as follows:

```
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ which mpif90
/usr/local/bin/mpif90
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ mpif90 -show
gfortran -I/usr/local/include -pthread -I/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi_usempi -lmpi_mpifh -lmpi
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ mpif90 -V
gfortran: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-V’
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ export MPI_LOC=/usr/local
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ export MPI_INCLUDE="$MPI_LOC"/includedan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ export MPI_LIB="$MPI_LOC"/lib
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MPI_LIB:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ export LIBMPI="-pthread -Wl -rpath -Wl -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lmpi -lmpi_usempi -lmpi_mpifh -lmpi"
```

With an additional step of:

```
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ make clean
/bin/rm -f *.o *.mod *.f90
```

Which brought me to where I am currently. My instinct is that the solution to my current problem will be similar to that of my previous problem. However, I am new to linux/c/fortran so I am not sure I fully follow the previous solution. As such the following commands produce the following output:

```
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ which mpicc
/usr/local/bin/mpicc
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ mpicc -show
gcc -I/usr/local/include -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi
dan@Dan-office ~/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source $ mpicc -V
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-V’
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Have I failed to correctly define some variables which is leading to this problem? I am conscious that this question is becoming rather long but I can add additional information if it is required such as the makefile (this is long though).

Comment: The problem with this command line `mpicc -c -O3 -I        func_pointer.c` is that you don't have an argument for the `-I` flag so it sees `func_pointer.c` as that argument which leaves it with no files to operate on. That being said I'm not at all certain I understand what problem you are actually having at this point or what the point of repeatedly showing us those bits of shell lines are supposed to be tellling us.

Comment: RE: the repeated lines of shell script. I thought it may have solved a similar problem to one I had previously so I though it may be pertinent to show them. I didn't understand that (possible) solution and I thought someone may explain them in any solution to my current issue. What does the `-I` flag do?

Comment: Those three commands `which mpicc`, `mpicc -show` and (the erroring) `mpicc -V` commands are *doing* nothing. The first just shows you where the binary is. The second just shows you what is presumably the command that it will run. The last is just passing `-V` to `gcc` which doesn't understand it and `gcc` then errors as it was given no files to operate on. The `-I` flag to `gcc` adds to the directories that `gcc` searches for include files in.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after encountering it again whilst compiling FVCOM on a new hard drive. The issue is, as raised by Etan, the `-I` flag. In the make.inc file uncomment the LIBDIR and INCDIR variables under local install and comment out the same variables directly above.